# Problem with my arduino board

Tags: arduino-uno

I had attatched a GSM module to my arduino Uno board. The power had been switched on. The GSM 5V pin was connected to my board. I was still midway with my work so for some reason I gave an external power supply to my GSM module. Now smoke started coming out of my Uno board and a burning smell came from it. I immediately switched off the power supply. But now I am unable to burn sketches to my Arduino. It is showing error: Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
On opening the serial monitor it says: Board at COM3 not detected.

Link from wher I bought the GSM module: http://www.ebay.in/itm/GSM-Module-SIM800-Quadband-better-than-SIM-900-or-SIM900A-Modem-with-SMA-Antenna-/252053758680?hash=item3aaf9322d8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops.

You let the [Magic Smoke™](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_smoke) escape from your Arduino.  Your Arduino is now somewhat dead.  Depending on *what* died it may be repairable by replacing components, or it may be beyond resurrection and it'll be easier to buy a new one.

Now - why did it happen?  Looking at the board in your link it should have been OK with the 12V power you provided, since it has its own regulator on board that can supposedly take up to 12V.  So one of two things may have happened:

1. What you thought was 12V was actually higher than 12V and the regulator didn't cope with it.
2. You connected the power backwards, so -12V was pumped straight through everything.

There seems to be no polarity protection on the board as far as I can see, and many regulators, if connected backwards, will just pass the power straight through with little or no change to it.  So my money is on having connected the power backwards.  Now, that might not be your fault, since on that site I can see no mention of which polarity the power connector uses - whether it is pin-positive or pin-negative.  The normal way (the way the Arduino board uses) is pin-positive, but that is not always the case.

Either way, the Arduino is now dead, and the GSM module may be dead as well. In fact the whole lot may be dead.

Comment: I provided 12V to the adapter. What about the GSM module?

Comment: Ouch. And what is the adapter?

Comment: SMPS Power adapter

Comment: What is the GSM module you are using?

Comment: The module I am using is sim800

Comment: And what is the module mounted on? And do I have to ask individually for every single little detail? Why can't you just tell us exactly what it is you have?!?!

Comment: GSM Module SIM800 Quadband with SMA Antenna. RS232 and TTL Output I2C, PWM, Inbuilt Bluetooth

Comment: That tells me absolutely nothing.  Please *edit* your question and include **links** to the **exact** products you are using.

Comment: I have put the link in the question

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: I had connected the 5v pin of the GSM to the arduino board and also connected the GSM with 12v adapter.

Comment: WHAT DO YOU MEAN BY THE WHOLE LOT?

Comment: I mean just that. There is a chance that everything might be dead. It's impossible to tell though without testing every single part.

Comment: I had 3 PIRs1 ultrasonic and 1 ht12e and 1 rf transmitter. what about those?

Comment: BTW how do I check if the GSM is working?

Comment: it would be nice if u were able to help me regarding this matter as I need to then place my orders soon.

Comment: Well, you know your Arduino is dead since you can't upload to it. The only way you can know if the GSM is dead is to plug it in to something and try using it. I cannot help you with that, my arms do not reach all the way to India. Instead YOU are going to have to investigate it for yourself.

Comment: Okay but what do you think about my other components. I tried checking my PIRs and they seem fine.

Comment: I didn't know you had any other components. If they seem fine they probably are fine. I am not psychic. I cannot test your components, and I do not even know what components you have since you haven't ever mentioned any other components. Use your brain. Try the components out. Get another Arduino and try them on that. Do not, under any circumstances though, repeat your previous disaster with your power supply.